# Change Number Generation Sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA script where for every 5 counts of the number, the numbering starts back at 1. I'm taking the user input to loop through how many times the user wants to have the number set. Problem is, the numbers are not restarting from 1. Please help!!

Example: user enters 2 times, expected result is-
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5

Code:

```
   Dim myValue, myRows As Variant
   Dim i, j, x, y, m, n, k As Integer
   Sub Button1_Click()
   'myValue = InputBox("Enter a starting number")
   myRows = InputBox("Enter how times to repeat")
   'Call repeat(myRows)
   Call repeat2(myRows)
   End Sub

   Sub repeat2(rep1)
   m = 0
   n = 0
   k = 1

   For k = 1 To myRows
   'k = k + 1
    m = m + 5
    n = n + 5
   Call autogen2(k)

   Next k

   End Sub

   Sub autogen2(z)
   For k = 1 To m + 5
   Range("F" & k).Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = k
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Next k
   End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger to see why it's not working as you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method seems overly complicated and loops through every cell instead of looping through groups of the target cells.

To simplify the math in calculating the target, I'd suggest `Option Base 1` as a compiler directive in the code sheet's declarations area. This changes the default for an array from zero based to one based; i.e. from `0 to 4` to `1 to 5`.

By using LBound and UBound, you can change the array without cahnging any of the other code that shapes the target.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim myRows As Long, seq As Variant
'myValue = InputBox("Enter a starting number")
    myRows = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter how times to repeat", Type:=xlNumbers)

    If IsNumeric(myRows) Then

        seq = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

        autogen seq, myRows

    End If

End Sub

Sub autogen(vals As Variant, n As Long)

    Dim k As Long

    For k = LBound(vals) To (n * UBound(vals)) Step UBound(vals)
        Cells(1, "F").Offset(k - 1, 0).Resize(UBound(vals), 1) = _
            Application.Transpose(vals)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for reviewing and providing a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Number Generator (Fast)

Adjust the constants (`Const`) to fit your needs.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim myRows As Variant

    myRows = InputBox("Enter how times to repeat")
    If IsNumeric(myRows) Then
        Repeat CLng(myRows)
    End If

End Sub

Sub Repeat(Rows As Long)

    Const cRange As String = "F1"   ' First Cell Range Address
    Const cStart As Long = 1        ' Starting Value
    Const cEnd As Long = 5          ' Ending Value

    Dim vntT As Variant             ' Target Array
    Dim i As Long                   ' Rows Counter
    Dim k As Long                   ' Value Counter
    Dim m As Long                   ' Target Array Row Counter

    ' Resize Target Array: Number of Values times Rows.
    ReDim vntT(1 To (cEnd - cStart + 1) * Rows, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through Rows.
    For i = 1 To Rows
        ' Loop through Values.
        For k = cStart To cEnd
            ' Count Target Array Row.
            m = m + 1
            ' Write current Value to element in current Target Array Row.
            vntT(m, 1) = k
        Next
    Next

    With Range(cRange)
        ' Clear contents of Target Column Range from First Cell Range to
        ' bottom cell.
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        ' Calculate Target Range: resize First Cell Range by Target Array Rows.
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        .Resize(m) = vntT
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 0):

One more:

```
Dim myRows As Long, tot As Long

myRows = Application.InputBox("Enter how times to repeat")
tot = myRows * 5

With ActiveSheet.Range("K1").Resize(tot, 1)
    .FormulaArray = "=1+MOD(ROW(1:" & tot & ")-1,5)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response.